# Statistics on Harry Potter chapter length

Tags: harry-potter, statistics

I'm looking for some statistics on typical Harry Potter chapter word count.

A nicely graphed distribution would be nice, but I'll accept an answer that has something equivalent to the average, standard deviation, and quartiles.

Comment: I'm mainly concerned with the series as whole, not each book separately. (But you can include that too if you want.)

Comment: You may want to specify an edition as the word counts may vary, unless that's insignificant enough that you don't care about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To calculate this answer I used the text from the official Pottermore ePubs (each chapter is saved as a seperate html file). I ran the htmls through [a utility I found](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/htmlastext.html) to convert them to txt, and then used the unix `wc -w` command to generate [a list of chapter word counts](https://pastebin.com/fNQLfweY). (Feel free to play around with the data on your own.)

I plugged this into excel and did a few calculations.

Note: All the below data uses the UK text. The American text tends to be a bit shorter.

- The longest chapter is Book 5, Chapter 13 - "Detention with Dolores" at 9,001 words.
- Not counting the epilogue, the shortest chapter is Book 3, Chapter 20 - "The Dementors’ Kiss" at 2,018 words.
- **The average chapter length is 5,547 words.**
- **The standard deviation is 1,525 words.**
- 50% of the chapters are between 4,464 and 6,613 words. (i.e. the first and third quartile)

Here is how the distribution looks with a bin width of 500 words.

[image]

However it's worth noting that some factors have a significant effect on chapter length, such as the length of the book and the position in the book.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Very interesting indeed. Could you draw some more general conclusions? For example about the author, writing time, profitability, etc

Comment: @Valorum - My goal here was literally wanting to know the average chapter length (ideally with some range to it, not just a single number). Conclusions are fun, but I think it would be overstepping my bounds here. Though what my data shows is that the bigger books not only have more chapters but longer length ones, and they tend to be longest towards the middle of the book.

Comment: You've not gonna believe this, but I was up to Prisoner of Azkaban doing individual word counts of all of the Pottermore ePubs myself! Can't remember exactly how I got Excel to calculate my standard deviation but it wasn't just using a built in function, I had to mess around with a few functions together to get the weighted one. Yours is about double mine, so I wonder if I factored a half into it accidentally.

Comment: @Ongo -  But how would you calculate standard deviation without even knowing all the chapter lengths? Unless I'm really misunderstanding how statistics works that seems completely impossible given your data.

Answer (score 6):

For the series as a whole, we can tabulate the number of chapters and length of the books, and find the weighted average of the length of a chapter (read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95909/why-is-an-average-of-an-average-usually-incorrect) to see what a weighted average is and why you can't just take an "average of averages").

[image: HP Chapter Stats]
 <sub>An Excel spreadsheet of my own devising. The number bold and in blue is the weighted average it calculated.</sub>

So the weighted average chapter length across the whole series is **5542 words** (rounded to the nearest whole word). If I had a source to determine the word length per chapter of each book, we could find a *weighted average per book* and then take a weighted average of that, but I don't imagine that'd stray too far from the 5542 calculated here.

Standard deviation is a little trickier, as with all of the different books to consider a weighted standard deviation would be more appropriate. After much toiling in Excel with the equation, I finally got a result of **747** (rounded to the nearest whole word, 746.5898815 exactly).

With these values, we can get a lovely normal distribution.

[image: Chapter Normally Distributed]
<sub>Using the weighted mean and weighted standard deviation, the chapter length can be normally distributed (see link at bottom to do this yourself). In this image, we can see that the probability of a chapter having more than 6000 words is about 27%.</sub>

Not sure how useful they'll be for you, but anyway the quartiles are as follows (nearest whole word):
**Q<sub>1</sub> = 5038

Q<sub>2</sub> = 5542

Q<sub>3</sub> = 6045**

**Sources for answer:**
Word length of chapters: [this website](https://wordcounter.io/blog/how-many-words-are-in-harry-potter/)
Number of chapters per book: [this other website](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_chapters_in_the_Harry_Potter_novels)
Normal Distributor (insert values yourself): [this nifty website](https://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~mbognar/applets/normal.html)

Comment: Interesting. So while DH is the longest book, it doesn't have the longest chapters. I didn't expect that

Comment: @Valorum Actually OotP is the longest book, and also has the longest average chapter length. DH is 2nd longest, while it has 3rd longest average chapter length. The table is just in book order rather than any numerical order.

Comment: -1 "With these values, we can **make an unfounded assumption of** a lovely normal distribution."

Comment: @Lexible Please elaborate on how to improve, I thought something like chapter length would be normally distributed.

Comment: I calculated the word count per chapter of the first book and most of the second book. I then realized the PDF for the second book was missing some sentences so the data may not have been reliable so I stopped. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHUyI.jpg) is the graph of the first book.

Comment: @Lexible Should I have taken some skew into account or something? I'll be happy to redo stuff, I just need to know where you think I've gone wrong, I was quite proud of my work but I'd hate for it to be out there and incorrect.

Comment: Ongo: *all* data have sample means and variances. That says nothing about the the shape of their *distribution*. The OP's question would be better served by a well-organized bar chart (e.g., a bar for each chapter, and chapters grouped differently in each chart: one for grouped by books, one for grouped by topics, one for grouped by starting, closing, middling, etc.). Alternately a histogram of word counts for each book, and one for the whole corpus.

Comment: Wait, how did you figure out the standard deviation without knowing the lengths of the 199 individual chapters? Unless I'm misunderstandings statistics that should be impossible to figure out from just looking at the total word count per book.

Comment: @Alex - I'd be grateful of you were to post an answer yourself. If you have a csv of the chapter lengths that would be great too.

Comment: @ibid I’d be happy to. But I can’t guarantee that the data will be perfectly accurate, as the PDF is corrupted in at least one place.

Comment: @Alex - I think I found an efficient way to get chapter word counts from my epubs. I may end up just self-answering this one.

Comment: @ibid Whatever works. I was pasting the text of each chapter into a word counter.

Comment: @Ongo - I did the math myself and I arrived at wildy different values for everything other than the mean chapter length.

Comment: @Ongo I'm very skeptical that the chapter lengths in the book follow a normal distribution; I would suspect the lengths follow a near-uniform distribution instead, meaning the sigma function you're using is probably not meaningful.